# what is the object layout of C++ under inheritance on gcc

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, gcc, layout

I'm tring to test the object layout of C++ under inheritance.
The following is my code

```
class A{    
    int val;    
    char bit1; 
}; 
class B:public A{   
    char bit2; 
}; 
class C:public B{
    char bit3; 
}; 
int main() {
    cout << sizeof(C);
    return 0; 
}
```

when I run it on Visual Studio 2019, The result is 16, I suppose it's layout should be this:

```
class A [8 bytes]{
    int val [4 bytes]
    char bit1 [1 bytes]
    [3 bytes padding]
}
class B [12 bytes]{
    A [8 bytes]
    char bit2 [1 bytes]
    [3 bytes padding]
}
class C [16 bytes]{
    B [12 bytes]
    char bit3 [1 bytes]
    [3 bytes padding]
}
```

but why don't B and C use A's 3 bytes padding to put bit2 and bit3?
which result will only be 8(with 1 byte padding).
I consider the following case

```
A *a;
B *b;
*b = *a
```

the content of bit2 will be covered if bit2 occupys A's padding

But on gcc 7.3.0, the result is actually 8.
By the way, if we change the access permissions of data members in A to public, the result will change to 12.
I want to know how gcc solve the problem mentioned above and why does the above result occur, thanks a lot!

Comment: The "why" on compiler internals is quite near impossible to answer. gcc uses Itanium ABI, which you may want to read.

Answer (score -1):

```
class A{
    int val;
    char bit1;
};
class B:public A{
  public:  // I added it for showing bit2 in the example below
    char bit2 = 1;
};
```

The class `A` is not a POD type, it has private members, thus its layout and the layout of the class `B` are implementation specific. And the code below is illegal

```
B b;
A* a = &b;
memset(a, 0, sizeof(A));  // b.bit2 is modified unintentionally in GCC.
```

If you declare the members of `A` public, the class `A` is a POD type and the code above must be valid, `b.bit2` is not placed  in `A`'s padding and isn't modified.

I can only guess it, MSVC seems to make class layouts equally regardless of if they are non POD types.